# Fade color and display text on image hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make thumbnails that on hover fades into a color and display text centered in the image. The images and text are different so I want them to display text specific to that image and not to the parent element. This is what I've got so far:

```html
<div id="latest_stuff">
                    <a href="www.example.com/video1"><img src="image2.jpg" alt="Video Thumbnail"></a>
                    <a href="www.example.com/video2"><img src="image2.jpg" alt="Video Thumbnail"></a>
                    <a href="www.example.com/video3"><img src="image2.jpg" alt="Video Thumbnail"></a>
                </div>
```

```css
#latest_stuff a{
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

#latest_stuff a:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Sorry if you don't understand, English is not my first language.

Answer (score 2):

I have created for one card you can follow for others

```css
#latest_stuff {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#latest_stuff a{
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

#latest_stuff:hover .overlay {
   opacity: 0.5;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="latest_stuff">
  <a href="www.example.com/video1">
   <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1035/5854/3903.jpg?hmac=DV0AS2MyjW6ddofvSIU9TVjj1kewfh7J3WEOvflY8TM" 
       alt="Video Thumbnail">
    <div class="overlay">
     <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I need. However it doesn't seem to work well with multiple images and streches to the size of the website. The images are fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I placed some dummy images.

```css
#latest_stuff a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

.img-caption {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 50%; /* 50% from top */
    left: 50%; /* 50% from left */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0); /* to center the text, scale(0) to doesn't show text  */
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

#latest_stuff a:hover .img-caption {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1); /* to center the text, scale(1) to show text  */
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

#latest_stuff a:hover img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="latest_stuff">
    <a href="www.example.com/video1">
        <img src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png" alt="Video Thumbnail">
        <div class="img-caption">
            Some dummy text
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="www.example.com/video2"><img src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png" alt="Video Thumbnail">
        <div class="img-caption">
            Some dummy text
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="www.example.com/video3"><img src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png" alt="Video Thumbnail">
        <div class="img-caption">
            Some dummy text
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```